# MATLAB: Creating a polygon out of points and masking its area in a plot

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a coastline file consisting of longitude and latitude points. Plotting it

```
plot(lat,lon)
```

will result in a connected plot of the points, thus forming a coastline.

I am performing 2D interpolation with the gridfit function [at the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit)

over the area of the figure. [image]

My objective is to mask off the land enclosed by the coastline and set the ocean (outside the mask) to white. So it looks like I have only extrapolated over the land.

I think the strategy is to turn the coastline points into a polygon and somehow into a mask?

Thanks!

Comment: "So it looks like I have only extrapolated over the land"...you mean to say you are fudging your results? :) Be careful how you word that; better just say "make it clearer to the reader which data are relevant" or so

Answer (score 0):

Use inpolygon to find the set of point coordinates that are outside the polygon. Substitute NaN for those that are outside.

You may need to ensure the polygon is a closed polygon, since it looks like your polygon stops at the edges of the grid. This simply means you need to add that point at the top left corner of the plot.

If that set of points that you have for the coastline is just a scattered list of points, i.e., they are not in order, then your real problem is how to make them into a polygon. I'd suggest a tool like [CRUST](http://www.voronoi.com/wiki/index.php?title=Crust_and_Skeleton) in that case.